# SublimeUI5 in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sapui5

During installation of SublimeUI5 in sublime Text I am facing a problem in 5th step actually. 
check the link for Installation: [GitHub (qmacro)](https://github.com/qmacro/SublimeUI5)
In console its throwing me an error saying:

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
> u'c:\\[sublime_install]\\Data\\Packages\\SublimeUI5\\Templates\\*.*
```

**Please check the below figure:** [image]

Comment: Why don't you open an issue of the GitHub page?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace [sublime_install] with proper path. For example,

let's say you cloned git repo to folder:

```
C:\Users\hollaajay\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages
```

NOTE: considering your username is "hollaajay' for Windows as well.

In your STProjectMaker settings you will have to write something like this:

```
{ "template_path" : "c:/users/hollaajay/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeUI5/Templates }
```